# Get the TOP 10 Countries have peoples age 40+ from their DOB ? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have table Persons where i have feilds

```
   pID , pName  , pDateOfBirth  , pCountry
```

now i have 10thousand peoples or above in database

**Question?** I want TOP 10 Name of coutries that is pCountry have persons age 40+?

my effort for that is

```
 select TOP 10  Count(pid) as ratio ,PCountry, datediff(pDOB, Date.Now) as 
 age where age >  '40' Group By country
```

what i want is this

```
      Pak = 555
      INDIA = 6666
      USA= 88
      Aus = 557
```

etc

Comment: Is this MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: query is sql so works by the way MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want a top of countries by number of persons aged 40+, so grouping should be by country only.

**Setup**

```
-- drop table Person
create table Person
(
    pID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY,
    pDateOfBirth DATE,
    pCountry VARCHAR(3)
)
GO

INSERT INTO Person (pDateOfBirth, pCountry)
SELECT TOP 1000 DATEADD(DAY, message_id, '19740101'), 'BEL' 
FROM sys.messages
GO

INSERT INTO Person (pDateOfBirth, pCountry)
SELECT TOP 1000 DATEADD(DAY, message_id, '19730101'), 'NED' 
FROM sys.messages
GO

INSERT INTO Person (pDateOfBirth, pCountry)
SELECT TOP 1000 DATEADD(DAY, message_id, '19760101'), 'DEU' 
FROM sys.messages
GO

INSERT INTO Person (pDateOfBirth, pCountry)
SELECT TOP 1000 DATEADD(DAY, message_id, '19750101'), 'ROM' 
FROM sys.messages
GO

INSERT INTO Person (pDateOfBirth, pCountry)
SELECT TOP 1000 DATEADD(DAY, message_id, '19740615'), 'USA' 
FROM sys.messages
GO
```

**Query**

```
DECLARE @today DATE = GETDATE()
DECLARE @age INT = 40

SELECT TOP 10 pCountry, COUNT(1) cnt
FROM Person
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, pDateOfBirth, @today) >= @age * 365.25
GROUP BY pCountry
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

I have used `DATEDIFF` with `day` option because using year will perform the difference at year level only, so that persons born in 19761201 will still be included (which is not correctly demographically speaking).

Also, `365.25` instead of `365` is used to compensate for leap years. However, this may still lead to 1-day error depending on the current date (I think this is more than reasonable when talking about age and large data).

**[edit]**

As correctly pointed out by `dnoeth`, date difference logic may be reverted and thus simplified. So, where condition becomes:

```
WHERE pDateOfBirth <= DATEADD(year, -40, @today)
```

Comment: `COUNT(1)` why you used this not count(*)

Comment: Generally, there is not difference between these two forms, but it seems that `COUNT(*)` may lead to poorer performance in some special cases - check [discussions from this article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/26/sql-server-select-1-vs-select-an-interesting-observation/)

Comment: The article you mention is from 2008, I might try to find an article from 1995 telling you that an EXISTS-subquery is executed once per outer row in SQL Server :-) Btw, you can simplify the WHERE-condition, instead of calculating the difference for each row, simply do it once: `WHERE pDateOfBirth <= dateadd(year,-40,getdate())`

Comment: @dnoeth - I thought about that, but `
 select datediff(year, '19761231', '20160101')` returns `40` and a person born in the last day of '76 is only 39 years old in the first day of 2016 :).

Comment: I don't get your comment, my calculation returns 1976-01-16 for today (2016-01-16) and every person born on this day or any day before is at least 40 years old.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I will fix the answer, as it is a little shorter and faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select TOP 10  Count(pid) as ratio, PCountry, datediff(YEAR,pDOB,GETDATE()) as ageInYear 
where datediff(YEAR,pDOB, GETDATE()) >  40 
Group By datediff(YEAR,pDOB, GETDATE()),PCountry
```

Comment: @Alexei sorry I can't comment anywhere because of reputation.
But where is ratio column

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

If you want to measure age in years, then don't use `datediff()`.  As is well documented, `datediff()` counts the number of time-unit ends between two dates.  That is, it returns one for the difference between '2015-12-31' and '2015-01-01'.  But it returns 0 for '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'.

Instead, use `dateadd()`:

```
where dob < daeadd(year, -40, getdate())
```

This applies to any solution you might choose.